How can I make Unison ignore git repositories?
Unison can ignore .git directories just fine,
Ignore = Name .git

but I'd like to make it ignore the entire repository (preferring instead to use git itself to synchronize anything across machines). For instance, if I have
MyProject/
  .git
  Makefile
  README.md
  src/
  test/

I'd like Unison to ignore the whole MyProject directory since it contains a .git subdirectory. I've tried
Ignore = Name */.git

but this still only ignores the .git directory itself. Is there a rule pattern that will exclude a parent directory based on its contents?

Are you wanting it to ignore any folder with a .git folder inside it, or just specific folders?

@music2myear Ideally anything with a .git directory inside of it. I could do a search and list out the ones I have inside of Unison's config, but I'd have to redo that or remember to add an entry each time I clone a repo. So, I'd like to use an automatic system if possible.
